# Is the State monad applicable to a simple recursive "loop"?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell from "LYAH" and got to the State monad. As an exercise I'm working on implementing a simple "virtual cpu". The state monad seems like a good fit for this but I can't figure out how to use it. Here's a very stripped down example of what I have at the moment (without the state monad):

```
data Instruction = Incr | Decr | Halt

data Computer = Computer { program :: [Instruction],
                           acc :: Int,
                           pc :: Int,
                           halted :: Bool
                         }

main = do
  let comp = Computer { program = [Incr, Decr, Incr, Incr, Halt]
                      , acc = 0
                      , pc = 0
                      , halted = False
                      }
  execute comp

execute :: Computer -> IO ()
execute comp = do
  let (output, comp') = step comp
  putStrLn output
  case halted comp' of
    False -> execute comp'
    True -> return ()

step :: Computer -> (String, Computer)
step comp = let inst = program comp !! pc comp
            in case inst of
                 Decr -> let comp' = comp{ acc = acc comp - 1,
                                           pc = pc comp + 1 }
                             output = "Increment:" ++
                                      "   A = " ++ (show $ acc comp') ++
                                      "  PC = " ++  (show $ pc comp')
                         in (output, comp')
                 Incr -> let comp' = comp{ acc = acc comp + 1,
                                           pc = pc comp + 1 }
                             output = "Decrement:" ++
                                      "   A = " ++ (show $ acc comp') ++
                                      "  PC = " ++  (show $ pc comp')
                         in (output, comp')
                 Halt -> let comp' = comp{halted = True}
                             output = "HALT"
                         in (output, comp')
```

My `step` function looks like the state monad but I can't see how to use it here. Would it be applicable? Would it simplify this code, or is this example better as it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. `step` can be translated quite mechanically:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

step :: State Computer String
step = do
   comp <- get
   case program comp !! pc comp of
    Decr -> do 
      let comp' = comp { acc = acc comp - 1
                       , pc = pc comp + 1 }
      put comp'
      return $ "Increment:"
                  ++ "   A = " ++ (show $ acc comp')
                  ++ "  PC = " ++  (show $ pc comp')
    Incr -> do
      let comp' = comp { acc = acc comp + 1
                       , pc = pc comp + 1 }
      put comp'
      return $ "Decrement:"
              ++ "   A = " ++ (show $ acc comp')
              ++ "  PC = " ++  (show $ pc comp')
    Halt -> do
      put $ comp{halted = True}
      return "HALT"
```

(These `let comp' = ...` are still a bit awkward. It could be made more imperative-like by using state field-modifiers from [the `lens` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).)

You may notice that [`State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:State) is actually just a specialization of the [`StateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT) transformer, and none of the functions I used is specific to this. I.e. you can straight away generalize the signature to

```
step :: Monad m => StateT Computer m String
```

That turns out to come in handy for `execute`, because there you intersperse the state modifications with `IO` side effects – exactly the kind of thing a transformer is for.

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

execute :: StateT Computer IO ()
execute = do
  output <- step
  liftIO $ putStrLn output
  comp <- get
  case halted comp of
    False -> execute
    True -> return ()
```

Finally, in `main` you just need

```
main = do
  let comp = ...
  evalStatT execute comp
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's going a bit outside what I'm familiar with (get and put are new to me) but I think I get the gist. However, there seem to be a couple of things not quite right in your example code and I can't quite figure it out. In particular the definition for `execute` refers to comp' but that's no longer defined there. How do I fix that?

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake.

Comment: OK - thanks. That makes sense, it works now. I think there are a couple more little typos in the first bit as well - leftovers from my original code -  `(output, comp')` and `in (output, comp')`?
I do have a follow-on question (if this is the right place to ask it):
What's the advantage (in this case) of using `StateT`? The new code is actually slightly longer than my original. If I understand it correctly the state becomes the monad "context", but since we have to explicitly access it via `get` and `put`, is this any benefit? Or does the benefit only show in more complex examples?

Comment: The main benefit is that you avoid explicitly creating many different copies of the state `Computer`, which (especially in bigger programs, yes) is quite bug-prone because it's so easy to accidentally pass on the wrong one. Again, this problem is still there to some degree in the version I showed, with the `let comp' = ...` definitions. As I wrote, `lens` tools can help there, but lenses are a whole separate realm of beginner-confusion, so I suggest saving that up for another time.

Comment: I think this is already what you meant to say in the previous comment, but rather than "explicitly creating" I'd say the problem is "naming" many different Computers. Of course, as you know, the same number of computers are created regardless; the bug you're talking about avoiding is accidentally using an old one that happens to still be in scope.